# The files from Ubuntu has been submitted successfully, but from the Windows I got the error "error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12)"

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, rsync, vps

If shortly, when I submit my files to VPS from Ubuntu PC by Rsync, everything going well, however if I do the same thing from Windows, I get the error

> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far)
>
> [Receiver] rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12)
> at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.3]

Although unlike Linux, the Rsync is not installed as default for the Windows, I have installed it Rsync on my Windows PC.

[image]

### Environment data

- Local PC#1: Windows 10
- Local PC#2: Ubuntu 20.04.5
- VPS: Ubuntu 20.04

### Preparations

I have initialized the VPS with clear Ubuntu.
To eliminate some the variables from equations, I have done some things which should not be done at real (not experimental as in my case) VPS because of security.

- I'll submit the data using the root account
- I will not use the SLL

Also, I have created the **/var/www/example.com** directory at VPS to avoid the error about unable to sync the data because the destination directory has not been created.

### Target

[image]

Submit the content of **06-ProductionBuild** directory to VPS.

### Experiment flow

On Windows terminal, input

```
rsync -azve ssh --progress 06-ProductionBuild root@160.XXX.XX.151:/var/www/example.com
```

The password has been requested. After inputting the password got:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.3]
```

[image]

If I just inputted the wrong password, the error was `Permission denied, please try again`.

Now same command from Ubuntu PC:

[image]

Everything was fine.

Please give me some hints.

---

Tried from WSL - it was fine.
Looks like something wrong with [Rsync from Windows](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/rsync/5.4.1.1).

[image]

Comment: Look through https://askubuntu.com/questions/625085/rsync-over-ssh-error-in-protocol-data-stream-code-12-ssh-works. It looks like you can get this code 12 error if the remote folder doesn't exist, or if rsync was not installed correctly. Make sure the folder exists, and try reinstalling rsync. Make sure that powershell isn't treating some part of your path as special characters and eating them

Comment: How exactly did you install rsync (mainly, where did you get it from)?

Comment: @TomYan, thank you for the comment. I have installed it via chocolatey, the package manager for Windows.

Comment: Download complete CygWin and don't use this standalone stuff.

Comment: @zomega Thank you for the recommendation. After installing the Cygwin, can I invoke the **rsync** from the normal windows terminal somehow? I need to do it for automation.

Comment: @TokugawaTakeshiYD Yes but if it doesn't work try running rsync from the CygWin console to see if it works there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is because you would be using the "system" `ssh` program (native build of OpenSSH from Microsoft) when you specify just `-e ssh`. (More precisely, it's probably because the PATH precedence of the `bin` directory of the (cw)rsync installation is lower than the other path in concern).

In my test the simpliest workaround is to specify `-e /bin/ssh` instead, which will make `rsync` use the (cygwin) `ssh` that comes with it. (The cygwin "magic" should automagically resolve the root of the path for you, chocolatey or not.)

Credit (of discovering the cause) goes to the comment [here](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/rsync#comment-5687073202), although the approach offered there seems unnecessarily clumsy. (Well, unless you have reason to use the `ssh` build from Microsoft.)

EDIT: actually the explanation given in the linked correct does not seem exactly true to me. In my test, the "system" ssh would indeed use `known_hosts` at a different location, but it prompts me to add the server to the list as well when I try to connect with it for the first time and created its own `known_hosts` successfully. It didn't ask me in the later attempt either so apparently it CAN find its own one to read back. Therefore I have no idea how his suggestion helped him and specifying the option/path doesn't work for me anyway.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. `-e /bin/ssh` has work. No one suspected the native build of OpenSSH for a long time.

Comment: Are the separate commands for Windows and UNIX-like systems are unearthly?

Comment: It's not really about UNIX-like vs Windows. It's really just about the location of the ssh executable and the PATH env var. If you *prepend* that location to PATH so that is before the the location of the native/system ssh, you then will not need `-e /bin/ssh`.